# Navigating through widgets using the TAB key

Tags: user-interface, gtk, pygtk, widget, gtkmm

What should I do in order to allow users to navigate through widgets using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key (in either Gtk or any derivative like gtkmm, pyGtk)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is build into the default "key_press_event" signal handler. If you set your own handler you must return FALSE from this handler because a TRUE means you have handled the key and no further processing is done. You can use this to avoid the default tabbing.

And i would like to add a question here, because i have no idea how i can do the  focus-next-widget, focus-prev-widget action programmatically.

Comment: to move focus next/prev, look at the child_focus method: (gtkmm) http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/2.99/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a8c564b6823adf744d14e258e661f453c or (gtk) http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-child-focus

Comment: Oh thanks! It turned out my signal handler returned wrong value. Great thanks, now everything is working!

Answer (score 1):

Is tabbing through your controls not working?  This should work out of the box as you build up your forms.  To customize the order of moving through the widgets as you tab, you use the set_focus_chain methods: [gtk](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-set-focus-chain), [pygtk](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcontainer.html#method-gtkcontainer--set-focus-chain), [gtkmm](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.0/classGtk_1_1Container.html#a9443a8dbbbcef4534244f2d036bf3535).